# How to change the structure of a Phonegap app without breaking it?

Tags: cordova

I want to change the structure of my Phonegap project while making sure that Phonegap recognizes it as a cordova-based project.

Phonegap seems to want a hierarchy like this:

[image]

I want one like this:

[image]

Where `www/` becomes `client/` and `config.xml`, `platforms/` and `plugins/` goes into `phongegap/`.

Of course changing the structure isn't so simple. When I try building the app, Phonegap complains that the `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`

Is there a good way of modifying the structure or am I forced to use what Phonegap wants.

Comment: why do you want to change the structure?

Comment: So the structure is consistent with other products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There didn't appear to be a way of telling Phonegap to conform to my structure, but I applied the following workaround.

I created the structure I wanted and added a `www/` directory to `phonegap/`.

Then in my gulpfile I created a task to copy everything from `client/` and `static/` to `phonegap/www/`.

The build process now looks like this:

1. Edit my code in `client/`
2. Run `gulp`
3. Resulting files from the build go into `static/`
4. Built and non-built files (from `static/` and `client/`) get copied to `phonegap/www/`
5. Navigate to `phongegap/`
6. Run phonegap's build command.

Simple.